# Dropdown region shipping

Tags: shipping, billing

In checkout page, when I select Portugal as country appears the image 1:

[image]

And after I change the country, for example I put Spain, and again I select Portugal and appears this:

[image]

I need that ALWAYS appear the second image. The dropdown.
I don't know what is happening. What is the problem?

Comment: All the caches are clean.

Answer (score 2):

By  ***default magento system does not have region list for Portugal***  So that,you have seen *this field as text area*.

Basically at `directory_country_region` table m agento save regions  details respectively country.You need to ***insert  Portugal regions details that table***.

For this case,you can flow the links as reference

- [How add indian State?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34259/how-add-indian-state)
- [adding-county-regions-states-provinces-in-magento](https://www.designhaven.co.uk/2015/06/adding-county-regions-states-provinces-in-magento-to-include-dropdown-in-cart/)