# India is select than state and city should be display

Tags: magento-1.9, country-regions

If user select "INDIA" country in billing step on checkout step
then indian state and city should be display in dropdown.

My default country is "USA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is saved **some countries state list** at database table
`directory_country_region`.Such as *like  USA,Canada*.

For india, ***state list does not exits in that table*** So,*state is not coming as* **dropdown**  at checkout.

So,you need to **insert states list of india at Table**.In this case,you need follow this link [How add indian State?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34259/how-add-indian-state)

But for ***city you need do some customization by follow*** the like [How add indian State?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34259/how-add-indian-state)

Comment: Hai Amit,   Let me know what are customization need to do city dropdown  in magento 2