# How to add provinces additional to states and regions

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address, billing-address

In my country we have states and then local provinces under each state.

I want to reflect this in the shipping address and billing address so the states are listed in a drop down just like countries. And then the user can select their local province after selecting a state.

I need some guidance on how to properly create the states and local provinces in the database and how to tell Magento to display them in the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the correction but can you also assist in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

follow this tutorial it may help you for adding new field

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page

or

http://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/how-to-add-custom-field-in-the-billing-and-shipping-address-of-onepage-checkout-in-magento/

for adding states as it is already there in magento

follow these links.

[How add indian State?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34259/how-add-indian-state)

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/31/magento-add-state-country-indian-states/

Comment: Thank you Arjun it worked well as I was able to create the states. The only draw back is that I did not find any tables for the city field in the database, how do I add the cities under each state.

Comment: For cities you need to add custom field. The above links might help you to create a custom field and you may search for other links as well on net.