# region/state code in tablerate.csv file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, table-rates, zipcode

i need to get the region/state code for Riyadh, Dammam, Jeddah.
or get me the zip/postal code range for the same cities.
pls help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to magento. what do you want to know? tell clearly. for ex: if you want to code for delhi, add 110002 like this. you mean this right?

Comment: i need the  region/state code for these cities in saudi arabia. my purpose is to fill the tablerate.csv file in magento2. i searched in the net, bt never got the answer. can u help me? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the state/region code from `directory_country_region` table in database.

Comment: i need the region/state code to enter into the tablerate.csv file.when i enter JED,RUH,DMM in these fields it shows error. actually i need to set different prices for these cities in the country saudi arabia.

Comment: in my database i checked for these cities, bt never got an answer.i'm new to magento ,so plz forgive me if i'm asking silly questions. thank you

Comment: Anu you need to add the states in the database first, here is the query you can run on your database to add indian states reference: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34259/how-add-indian-state

Comment: Like wise first add the states of country you want to the database

Comment: thankz nitin. i have one doubt, from where i get the state codes for saudi arabia. is there is any standard codes for those cities. or can i insert into  db according to my wish?

Comment: You can add it according to you.

Comment: thank u so much nitin , thankz for the help. :)

Comment: hi, is there is any other way to get csv file of cities in saudi arabia? bcoz writing it is too hard :)

Comment: You can get it from wiki and make a list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_Saudi_Arabia :)

Comment: once again thnk u...

Comment: Glad to heat that it helped you.