# How to implement CGST, SGST and IGST in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I wants to implement **CGST ,SGST and IGST** in my store that is if customer shipping address is current state it apply CGST and SGST. and if customer shipping address is other state then its apply IGST. i had tried this link

```
[https://magecomp.com/blog/create-gst-tax-rule-magento/][1]
```

to for CGST and SGST it working fine for all state customer but not able to implement IGST with required condition. Please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Create 2 tax rules for IGST with pin code range. 1st one is IGST with pin code range starting from [110000 to (Lower bound of your state pin code - 1)] & 2nd one is IGST. with pin code range starting from [(upper bound of your state pin code + 1 ) to 999999]. Indirectly we are excluding your state pin code range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 : Go to **Sales > Tax > Product Tax Classes** Create Product tax class , say **GST TAX**....

[image]

Step 2 : Go to **sales  > Tax > Manage Tax zones and Rates** & Create tax rates

[image]

[image]

step 3 : Go to **Sales > tax > Manage Tax rules** , create new tax rule

[image]

[image]

Comment: in my admin panel state dropdown is disable how to enable it

Comment: @Neeya once you select the country India from dropdown , than you can see an option to select states from another dropdown.....

Comment: india state is already selected in country dropdown still state dropdown not enabled

Comment: @Neeya go to `system` > `configuration` > `General` > go to `states option` , than select `india` and than check.....

Comment: still not enabled

Comment: @Neeya system > configuration > sales > tax > Default Tax Destination Calculation > select india in country and select * in states and than check......

Comment: sir in this section i already done same setting but state dropdown not enabled i cant able to find out exact reason

Comment: @Neeya check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322312/states-drop-down-missing-magento ....

Comment: yes now able to see state.

Comment: @Neeya okay, than try according to my answer.......

Comment: state having dropdown list so how can i apply IGST to multiple state

Comment: @Neeya you need to create IGST by selecting each state once..... means For each state you need to create separate IGST.....

Comment: i go through your answer but where can i find tax percent in invoice or checkout page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63981/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-neeya).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to implement ***Indian GST in Magento 1.9***:

**Step 1:** Navigate to **Sales > Tax > Product Tax Classes** and click **Add New**.

[image]

**Step 2:** Name the product tax class as GST to easily identify the tax class while creating tax rules and rates for all 3 SGST, CGST, and IGST.

[image]

**Step 3:** Before creating tax rates, follow this [guide to install states](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34259/how-add-indian-state) script to get auto state selection for Indian states. Now navigate to **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates** to create tax rates for CGST, SGST, and IGST. While creating tax rates, set 6% of rate and Gujarat as the business origin for both CGST and SGST. And for IGST, you have to create 28 rates of 12% IGST for all the states other than Gujarat to make GST work for all the states of India. Click save once all the rates have been created.Before creating tax rates, follow this guide to install states script to get auto state selection for Indian states. Now navigate to **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates** to create tax rates for CGST, SGST, and IGST. While creating tax rates, set 6% of rate and Gujarat as the business origin for both CGST and SGST. And for IGST, you have to create 28 rates of 12% IGST for all the states other than Gujarat to make GST work for all the states of India. Click save once all the rates have been created.

[image]

**Step 4:** Once all the 3 tax rates are created, they can be seen enlisted under **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates**.

[image]

**Step 5:** Whenever the selling is performed intra-state, SGST and CGST are equally divided into two halves of the whole rate of the GST, i.e., 6% to make the complete 12%.
As per the government rule, sellers have to bifurcate CGST, SGST and IGST separately in order details and invoices for every single order. To split CGST-SGST equally into two, you have to custom code as below.
Go to **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/tax.phtml** and find the blow code at line number 54.
    
                getValueProperties()?> rowspan=" 1 ">
                    formatPrice($amount); ?>

Replace the above code with:
    
               " class="a-right" rowspan="1 ">
                   helper('checkout')->formatPrice($amount / ($percent/(float)$rate['percent'])); ?>

**Step 6:** Create tax rules from **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules** for all the 3 CGST, SGST and IGST. Select product tax class as GST and tax rate for each of them respectively as created.

[image]

**Step 7:** Once tax rules are created and saved, they can be seen enlisted under **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules**.

[image]

**Step 8:** Enable the “Display Full Tax Summary” in **System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings** to show detailed tax summary with the bifurcation of CGST-SGST and IGST.

[image]

**Step 9:** To assign tax class as GST to all the products, simply go to **Catalog > Manage Products**, select all the products, select Update Attributes from the Action drop-down, go to Tax Class, tick Change and set GST from the drop-down and save.

[image]

**Step 10:** Add a product to cart and select the country as India and state as Gujarat for testing the implementation. The SGST and CGST tax rate will be applied on order.

[image]

**Step 11:** To test the IGST, select a different state in the above step.

[image]
Apply SGST, CGST and IGST in Magento 1.9 by following the above steps.

**Source Credit:** https://meetanshi.com/blog/apply-indian-gst-in-magento/

Comment: i have these settings but taxes are not showing in cart

Comment: you assign tax class to product?