# Magento list states and cities according to website specific for India

Tags: magento-1.9, registration, country-regions

How to list **states** and **cities** according to website specific for India

Answer (score 2):

For cities you have to add select list ( drop down ) which will have all Indian cities list and toggle select list ( for indian country ) and input field ( for others ) on country drop down.

So if someone select India it should display drop down and hide input field.

However, for states you can check this post [Add Indian States](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34259/how-add-indian-state) Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks I have added the states for India but say suppose If I select Telangana State.province should display Hyderabad or some other

Comment: For that, either you create module to add cities with their respective state or do that using jQuery with some little magic, i.e Add state code before the city name ( like. TL-Hyderabad ). if someone selects Telangana Match TL and filter out the list of cities.

Comment: ok thanks for the idea, i will check this flow